# Using SystemJS with Karma - 404 on package.json

Tags: angularjs, npm, karma-jasmine, systemjs, karma-systemjs

**Problem:**

Attempting to integrate SystemJS config with Karma using [karma-systemjs](https://github.com/rolaveric/karma-systemjs), however Karma is complaining about not being able to find the package.json file for each import:

```
...
10 07 2017 13:38:15.107:WARN [web-server]: 404: /node_modules/angular-mocks/package.json
10 07 2017 13:38:15.380:WARN [web-server]: 404: /node_modules/moment/package.json
10 07 2017 13:38:15.382:WARN [web-server]: 404: /node_modules/angular/package.json
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/node_modules/angular-mocks/package.json
    Error loading http://localhost:9876/node_modules/angular-mocks/package.json
    Error loading build/js/app.spec.js

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.945 secs / 0 secs)
```

Above has been truncated, but there are several more missing package.json warnings above the output. Also these errors only relate to Karma, actually application itself runs fine with below setup.

**Dependency Versions:**

- `"karma": "1.7.0"`
- `"karma-jasmine": "1.1.0"`
- `"karma-systemjs": "0.16.0"`
- `"systemjs": "0.19.47"`

**SystemJS Config:**

(Referenced from: https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/767#issuecomment-139515090)

```
System.config({
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "babel",
  babelOptions: {
    "optional": [
      "runtime",
      "optimisation.modules.system"
    ]
  },
  paths: {
    '*': './node_modules/*',
  },
  packageConfigPaths:  ['./node_modules/*/package.json'],
  map: {
    'systemjs': './node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js',
    'system-polyfills': './node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
    'babel': './node_modules/babel-core/browser.js',
    'angular-feature-flags': './node_modules/angular-feature-flags/dist/featureFlags.min.js',
    crypto: '@empty',
    fs: '@empty',
    stream: '@empty'
  }
});
```

**Karma Config:**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  "use strict";
  config.set({
    autoWatch: true,
    singleRun: false,
    port: 9876,
    frameworks: ["systemjs", "jasmine"],

    babelPreprocessor: {
      options: {
        compact: true
      }
    },

    files: [
      "node_modules/phantomjs-polyfill-object-assign/object-assign-polyfill.js",
      {pattern: "app/assets/images/**/*", watched: false, included: false, served: true},
      "build/**/*spec*.js"
    ],

    systemjs: {
      configFile: "./config.js",
      serveFiles: [
        './build/**/*.js'
      ]
    },
    browsers: ["PhantomJS"],
    reporters: ["spec"]
  });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

`karma-systemjs` is supposed to read your SystemJS configuration and automatically tell `karma` to serve the files that you tell SystemJS about. However, I looked at the code of `karma-systemjs` and I don't see any provision there to deal with `packageConfigPaths`. (And the project [needs a new maintainer](https://github.com/rolaveric/karma-systemjs), which does not inspire confidence.) Therefore, you should add an element to your `files` configuration like:

```
{ pattern: "node_modules/**/package.json", included: false }
```

I'm suggesting a pattern with `**` so that you can automatically handle paths like `node_modules/@angular/core/package.json`, which are more than one level deep.

Comment: Tried your suggestion, however issue is still persisting with no change in error output.